# Using types defined in C header in Fortran

Tags: makefile, compilation, fortran

I am on a 64 bit machine runing RHEL 6.7  with gfortran 4.4.7.

I am trying to build a static library from a code base that looks like this

```
└── root
    ├── C_src
    │   └── foo.h
    ├── Fortran_src
        |──Makefile
        |── <other files>
        └── foo.f90
```

My `Makefile` simply lists all of the `*.f90` files and makes `.o` files out of them.

When trying to build `foo.f90` using the command

```
gfortran -c -I. foo.f90 -o
```

I get the following error

```
TYPE (MY_TYPE), INTENT (OUT) :: PassesOutput 
       1
Error: derived type 'mytype' at (1) is being used before it is defined
```

However after some digging I found that this type is being defined in `foo.h`

```
typedef struct{
    <bunch of stuff>
} MY_TYPE
```

Is there a way to build this code so that fortran is able to know about the type definition in `foo.h` when trying to compile `foo.f90`?

Comment: Is the library written by you? Is the complete code supposed to be compilable?

Comment: I mean, perhaps the type is correctly defined in a Fortran file you did not find yet. But we don't have enough data, this is very far to a real [mcve]. So that's why we can answer only your queation in the title, but not solve your compilation troubles (se *XY problem*).

Comment: @VladimirF No, the library is not written by me.  It's a piece of legacy code whose original `Makefile` is long lost. I suspect that the code is compilable because included are the completed `.a` files for different architectures

Comment: In that case you are probably asking a wrong question. The answer of Marcus below is correct, but will not help you compiling it, because it is a wrong question. See my previous comment.

Comment: @VladimirF I took one of those `.a` files and ran `ar x <libname>` on it to see what files were included in that library, after that I tried to compile them on my own system and that's when I ran into this problem

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  The type must be defined in one of the Fortran files. Use grep or similar tool to find it. Then probably ask a new question, show all the relevant code, the Makefile, the errors,...

Comment: @VladimirF I'm not sure what's wrong with the question I asked.  I think I stated my problem correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163494/discussion-between-roscoe-and-vladimir-f).

Comment: Nope, you didn't.  Have you *really* read the links? You are asking *"Is there a way to build this code so that fortran is able to know about the type definition in foo.h when trying to compile foo.f90?"* You should be asking: *"How to compile this program? It gives me these errors for this code."*

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please do not rewrite your question, when you already received questions. Especially when those questions are already upvoted. You can accept this question and **start a new question** with all those important details. Do nut just rewrite the the title, **add all those important details!!!**. Do search in your source files. Do find where the type is defined. Do show us your code. Do that in a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and Fortran are different languages. Though Fortran compilers typically support the *C calling convention*, that means that you can call C functions from fortran and the other way around. It doesn't mean the type information is parsed from the same syntax.

In other words: C headers are C headers, not fortran type definitions.

C simply has the ability to build types that Fortran can't have, and Fortran has types that C doesn't. So, there's no straight-forward translation between these worlds in general. If your C function takes a type that there's no direct equivalent for in fortran, you'll simply have a bad time.

So: nope, unless you have write some wrapper code, this won't work. There's automatic wrapper generators, but their complexity imho doesn't make sense in the use case you're describing. Seriously, if you can, avoid things like SWIG.